# KVM and Libvirt: Bad CPU/Network performance of guest

Tags: linux, networking, kvm, qemu, libvirt

I have an Arch Linux host which runs virtualised router.

When using a LXC guest as router, everything is fine. I get 100MBits Up/Down and almost no CPU usage at all.

However, when I use libvirt gest (pfSense FreeBSD) as a router, whenever there is heavy network traffic going through the guest, the CPU usage goes unreasonably high (up to 100%) but the worst thing is that the network throughput is halved! I get 45-49Mbits max.

Host doesn’t support PCI pass through, so this is my config for the libvirtd VM:

```
Nic1 (wan)
Network source: Direct ‘eth0’
Source mode: passthrough
Device model: virtio

Nic2 (lan)
Bridge name: br0
Device model: virtio
```

I tried e1000 instead but it changes absolutely nothing.

```
Host CPU: AMD A4-5000 Kabini
Guest CPU: default or Opteron_G3
```

Hardware polling in pfSense is disabled, and pfSense ifconfig shows this: http://storage5.static.itmages.com/i/16/1217/h_1481996196_8871112_a2f0d75655.png

This has been so since over a year now, since I started using KVM. If I do not solve this problem, I will have to dump libvirt because such performance is unacceptable.

Comment: How can there be a "passthrough" virtio? Do you use macvtap maybe? In any case, it is normal for a fully virtualized guest to have more overhead than a container. You are also using very non-standard distros - BSD and Arch both. I would try to reproduce the issue on Centos as guest and host before anything else

Comment: Yes, it is using macvtap. I realise full virtualisation has its overheads, but this overhead is much to large. If people had it, no-one would use pfSense as a VM, and many do. And sorry, but Arch is a very standard distro. Also, pfSense is just FreeBSD. If there is a problem on such a pure and barebone linux  as Arch, there is no reasonable cause to think it might be not there on a something like Centos.

Comment: Ok stay stubborn and slow if you wish

Answer (score 1):

This is to do with the FreeBSD drivers for Virtio, they are simply not up to the task to run as fast as Linux drivers.

https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/poor-virtio-network-performance-pfsense-guest-proxmox-3-4.23933/

^^ the above is a post that details a few things you can do to help suchas turning off Hardware Checksum Offload on the guest and host and also within pfSense settings (be sure to reboot VM before re-testing).

I have been trying to run pfSense on top of Proxmox (Debian base) and on gig interfaces on bare metal get 940-980 Mbps but on VM guest get a max of 650-700 Mbps.